# Parse text of element with empty element inside

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to convert an XHTML document that uses lots of tables into a semantic XML document in Python using xml.etree. However, I'm having some trouble converting this XHTML

```
<TD>
  Textline1<BR/>
  Textline2<BR/>
  Textline3
</TD>
```

into something like this

```
<lines>
  <line>Textline1</line>
  <line>Textline2</line>
  <line>Textline3</line>
</lines>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the text after the BR elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the .tail property of the <br> elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

doc = """<TD>
  Textline1<BR/>
  Textline2<BR/>
  Textline3
</TD>
"""

e = et.fromstring(doc)

items = []
for x in e.getiterator():
    if x.text is not None:
        items.append(x.text.strip())
    if x.tail is not None:
        items.append(x.tail.strip())

doc2 = et.Element("lines")
for i in items:
    l=et.SubElement(doc2, "line")
    l.text = i

print(et.tostring(doc2))
```

Comment: aarrgghh use `if foo is not None:` not `if foo != None`

Comment: Of course you're right John, I normally would. I've just spent the last 9 hours coding Java though so I slipped :(

Comment: You must have committed a really serious offence to merit such a sentence as 9 hours Java coding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the tags being empty is your problem. xml.etree may not expect you to have child elements and bare text nodes mixed together.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is great for parsing XML or HTML that isn't well formatted:

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(open('in.html').read())
print "\n".join(["<line>%s</line>" % node.strip() for node in soup.find('td').contents if isinstance(node, BeautifulSoup.NavigableString)])
```